# SQL Server Recursion - Query Assistance to calculate current & overall totals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a recursion scenario i am trying to solve but have not been able to do it using TSQL & am asking for expertise and assistance.

**Scenario:**
I am dealing with Course Sessions & numbers of students enroled on these sessions.
Each year a number of students enroll in the first session, or graduate to the next session.

Sessions look like this:

[image]

Each session knows the id of the next session.
e.g. studentse start on session year 1 in 2015 and move on to session year 2 in 2016.
The last session has no nextSessionID.

End goal is to get the sessions in order with two aggregates:

1. the total that joined in the first session.
2. the total on the current session.
   (note - totals listed here are arbitrary values, and don't match the sample data below)
   [image]

**What i have tried:**
I have worked out how to get the nextSessionID.
I then tried putting this in a recursive CTE. I have not been able to get this to go more than 1 level deep however.

I would appreciate some pointers on what direction to take this.
Code to create sample tables & data is listed below.

Appreciate any help and expertise.

```
--create session table
create table #sessions
(
sessionInstanceID int,
SessionYear int,
AcademicYear int,
NextSessionInstanceID int
)


--populate session table
insert into #sessions(sessionInstanceID,SessionYear, AcademicYear, NextSessionInstanceID)
values( 1001    ,   1   ,   2015    ,   1006),
(   1002    ,   2   ,   2015    ,   1007),
(   1003    ,   3   ,   2015    ,   1008),
(   1004    ,   4   ,   2015    ,   null),
(   1005    ,   1   ,   2016    ,   1009),
(   1006    ,   2   ,   2016    ,   1010),
(   1007    ,   3   ,   2016    ,   1011),
(   1008    ,   4   ,   2016    ,   1012),
(   1009    ,   1   ,   2017    ,   null),
(   1010    ,   2   ,   2017    ,   null),
(   1011    ,   3   ,   2017    ,   null),
(   1012    ,   4   ,   2017    ,   null)


--create enrolment table 
create table #enroledStudents
(
     
    sessionInstanceID int,
    studentID int
)


--populate enrolment table 
insert into #enroledStudents
values(1001, 1)
,(1001, 2)
,(1001, 3)
,(1001, 4)
,(1001, 5)
,(1001, 6)
,(1002, 1)
,(1002, 3)
,(1002, 4)
,(1002, 5)
,(1002, 6)
,(1003, 1)
,(1003, 3)
,(1003, 4)
,(1004, 1)
,(1005, 10)
,(1005, 11)
,(1005, 12)
,(1005, 13)
,(1006, 11)
,(1006, 12)
,(1006, 13)
,(1007, 11)
,(1007, 12)
,(1007, 13)
,(1008, 24)
,(1008, 25)
,(1008, 26)

    
    --get sessions & the next academicSessionID
    select s.sessionInstanceID as currentInstanceID, s.SessionYear as currentSessionYear, s.AcademicYear as currentAcademicYear,
    s2.sessionInstanceID as nextSessionInstanceID , s2.SessionYear as nextSessionYear, s2.AcademicYear as nextAcademicYear
    from #sessions s
    left join #sessions s2 on s.AcademicYear = s2.AcademicYear - 1
    and s.SessionYear = s2.SessionYear -1

with cte as
(
    select * from #sessionsHierarchy
    union all
    
    select #sessionsHierarchy.* 
    from cte 
    join #sessionsHierarchy on cte.nextSessionInstanceID = #sessionsHierarchy.currentInstanceID

    
)
select cte.currentInstanceID, cte.currentAcademicYear, cte.currentAcademicYear,
--count()
from cte
join #enroledStudents on cte.currentInstanceID = #enroledStudents.sessionInstanceID
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

After quite a bit more data exploration it became clear that this was quite difficult to do in a set based manner.

I defined the problem as needing to add the intake year for all sessions.
The criteria for this is a little convoluted so the easiest solution was a bit of python and a few loops! not as elegant as i liked but the result is as required and its robust.

thank you for the advice and help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what results you want, but this will get you all the results ordered by starting `sessionInstanceID` then by what order in the chain.

We also calculate total students for the session

```sql
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
      sessionInstanceID,
      NextSessionInstanceID,
      AcademicYear,
      startingId = sessionInstanceID,
      lvl = 1
    FROM sessions s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM sessions s2
      WHERE s2.NextSessionInstanceID = s.sessionInstanceID)

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
      s.sessionInstanceID,
      s.NextSessionInstanceID,
      s.AcademicYear,
      cte.startingId,
      cte.lvl + 1
    FROM cte 
    JOIN sessions s on s.sessionInstanceID = cte.nextSessionInstanceID
)
SELECT
  sessionInstanceID,
  AcademicYear,
  StartingTotalStudents = (
        SELECT TotalStudents = COUNT(*)
        FROM enroledStudents e
        WHERE e.sessionInstanceID = cte.startingId
    ),
  TotalStudents = (
        SELECT TotalStudents = COUNT(*)
        FROM enroledStudents e
        WHERE e.sessionInstanceID = cte.sessionInstanceID
    )
FROM cte
ORDER BY startingId, lvl;
```

[db<>fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9162085f78577f592a171143f262dd52)

Comment: thanks, that helps a lot. Apologies for the lack of clarity. to simplify, i think the main goal is to be able to order the sessions, in the order a student progresses through them. i.e. student starts in academicYear 2015 sessionYear 1, progresses to AcademicYear 2016 sessionYear 2, then academicYear 2017 session year 3 and so on. there is no way to order sessions like this, or a grouping column to allow easy selection of these sessions.